# ffmpeg: why metadata of audio tracks is not written?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to change the metadata of my avi.

```
ffmpeg -y -i oldvhs.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng  -metadata:s:a:1 language=ita -metadata:s:v:0 title="The old movie" -map 0 new-oldvhs.avi
```

When I use mplayer for testing

```
mplayer -aid 1 new-oldvhs.avi OK
mplayer -aid 2 new-oldvhs.avi OK
```

But when i try the alang..

```
mplayer -alang ita new-oldvhs.avi #SPEAK ENGLISH!
mplayer -alang eng new-oldvhs.avi #SPEAK ENGLISH!
```

I open the file with mediainfo and avidemux and metadata tracks is not written, mediainfo report nothing, avidemux report unknown.
Where is the fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround using mkv.

```
ffmpeg -y -i oldvhs.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0 -metadata:s:a:0 language="eng" -metadata:s:a:1 language="ita" -metadata:s:v:0 title="The old movie" oldvhs.mkv
```